# How to set background-color in only last row of tr which is dynamically generated using php

Tags: php, html, css

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <?
        $count=0;
        $i=1;
        foreach($gallery as $key => $list1)
        {
            $count++;
            ?>
            <td>
                <img src='<?echo base_url();?>userfiles/eventsgallery/small/<?=$list1['image'];?>'>
            </td>
            <? // style='background:red;'
            if($count % 4 == 0 )
            {
                $color = ""; 
                $i++;
                if($i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    $color = "style='background:orange;'";  
                }
                else
                {
                    $color = "style='background:black;'";
                }
                echo "</tr><tr ".$color.">";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Add a class to last row with If statement. And style this class.

Comment: is CSS' `:last-child` an option?

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo to achieve that..

```
table.class_name tr:last-child {
   background: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/S9DTR/)

Answer (score 0):

...in css:

```
 .table1 tr:last-child {
        background-color: #0B615E;
        }



<table width="100%" class="table1">

        <tr>
              <?
            $count=0;
            $i=1;
              foreach($gallery as $key => $list1)
               {
                  $count++;

                  ?>                       
                         <td>                                                   
                           <img src='<?echo base_url();?>userfiles/eventsgallery/small/<?=$list1['image'];?>'>
                         </td>          

                    <?
                        // style='background:red;'
                        if($count % 4 == 0 )
                        {
                            $color = ""; 
                            $i++;
                            if($i % 2 == 0)
                            {
                              $color = "style='background:orange;'";  
                            }
                            else
                            {
                              $color = "style='background:black;'";
                            }

                            echo "</tr><tr ".$color.">";


                        }

              }?>
          </tr>
          </tr>
          </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would need to do it in your php loop, you can reverse your counter:

```
<?php
$count = count($gallery);
foreach($gallery as $key => $list1) {
        $lastClass = $count == 1?' lastrow':'';
        $count--;
        ?>
       html here
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<table width="100%" id="your_table_id">
    <?
        $count=0;
        $i=1;
        $size = sizeof($gallery);
        foreach($gallery as $key => $list1) {
            $count++;
            $color = ""; 
            if($size==$count) {
                $color = "style='background:orange;'";  
            }
    ?> 
    <tr <?php echo $color;?>>
        <td>                                                   
            <img src='<?echo base_url();?>userfiles/eventsgallery/small/<?=$list1['image'];?>'>
        </td>    
    </tr>       
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

OR you can Add a CSS Like this as [@Mr. Alien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21954352/1542290) answered

```
#your_table_id tr:last-child {
   background: orange;
}
```

Comment: Just copied the CSS snippet and changed the id and property?

Comment: Yup, mentioned after I commented :) didn't downvoted but you had some bad intentions though.. make sure you don't copy like this ahead..

Answer (score -1):

Use `:last-child`

**CSS**

```
table tr:last-child {
   background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Or

**jQuery**

```
$("table tr").last().css('background','#ccc')
```

I gave jQuery option too because `:last-child` CSS selector has compatibility issue

Hope this is what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/Xen99/

Comment: The `:last-child` CSS selector is not supported in IE8 and earlier versions.